# Change color of table cell border

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I want to be able to change color of any table cell border.
I've decided to not use border-left, border-right, etc, because it's not possible to make it pixel-perfect. Different browsers render it in a different way. Especially in borders intersection area.
I came up with the approach, but it's not working in IE as I expected:

[image]

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            line 1
            <div class="left-border"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            line 1<br>
            line 2
        </td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

tr {
    vertical-align: top;
}

td {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
}

.left-border {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/dv1oqopL/5/

Comment: you can set the overflow:hidden to td and set the height of div manually more than height of td like 100px. it will show the full height border as in other browser

Comment: @DeepakSharma border will became invisible if you set `overflow: hidden;`.

Comment: you want to change the `border-color` of every `<td>` ?

Comment: @JohnReyM.Baylen no. I want to be able to change the color of any border of any cell. Everything works fine in my case, the problem is in IE. But I can't really blame IE for that cause `position: relative;` for `td` element is undefined by CSS standart. So I need some IE fix or different approach.

Answer (score 1):

well IE is a B***h as always, it just calculates the height of the td based on it's own content so I have no clean fix for you but a hack that might solve your issue is to add

```
border-left:1px solid #000;
```

on that td, this will fill the border underneath your div and look the part an all browsers.